# Creating a tensorflow dataset that outputs a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dict with "metadata" for my dataset, of sort 
`{'m1': array_1, 'm2': array_2, ...}.` Each of the arrays has shape (N, ...), where N is the number of samples.

The question:
Is it possible to create a [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) that outputs a dictionary `{'meta_1': sub_array_1, 'meta_2': sub_array_2, ...}` for each iteration of the datasets iterator.get_next()? Here, sub_array_i should contain the ith metadata for one batch, so should have shape (batch_sz, ...).

What I tried so far is using [tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator), like this:

```
N = 100
# dictionary of arrays:
metadata = {'m1': np.zeros(shape=(N,2)), 'm2': np.ones(shape=(N,3,5))} 
num_samples = N

def meta_dict_gen():
    for i in range(num_samples):
        ls = {}
        for key, val in metadata.items():
            ls[key] = val[i]
        yield ls

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(meta_dict_gen, output_types=(dict))
```

The problem with this seems to be in `output_types=(dict)`. The code above throws at me a

> TypeError: Expected DataType for argument 'Tout' not < class 'dict'>.

---

I'm using tensorflow 1.8 and python 3.6.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Datasets are sequences of elements, each of which may be composed of one or more tensors (allowing for nested structures) having fixed type and shape (although the shape may be only partially specified). The only variation that they admit is whether you want to produce dense or sparse tensors. Keep in mind that TensorFlow graphs must be language-agnostic, since they can be used in different languages, so native types like dictionaries cannot be directly supported. However you can add your metadata within each element, as long as the structure is fixed.

Comment: So, it's possible to have an output tuple with all the metadata as separate tensors inside, but it's not possible to keep the headers? Ok, I'll find a workaround then. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Actually, as I remember from looking again at the guide, you can have named tuples as outputs of the iterator (see [Dataset Structure](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#dataset_structure)), which is not exactly the same as a dict but kinda close. However it's shows you an example for `from_tensor_slices`, I'll see if there's a way to do the same with `from_generator`...

Comment: Right, so scratch that, you _can_ do what you want (see answer). Graph operations still work at tensor level, but the dataset API does implement this functionality (I thought that the nesting behavior only worked for tuples).

Comment: Yes, it seems to work so far, also in combination (zipped) with other datasets. Even if some tensors have 'headers', others don't. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So actually it is possible to do what you intend, you just have to be specific about the contents of the dict:

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

N = 100
# dictionary of arrays:
metadata = {'m1': np.zeros(shape=(N,2)), 'm2': np.ones(shape=(N,3,5))}
num_samples = N

def meta_dict_gen():
    for i in range(num_samples):
        ls = {}
        for key, val in metadata.items():
            ls[key] = val[i]
        yield ls

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    meta_dict_gen,
    output_types={k: tf.float32 for k in metadata},
    output_shapes={'m1': (2,), 'm2': (3, 5)})
iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_elem = iter.get_next()
print(next_elem)
```

Output:

```
{'m1': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32>,
 'm2': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(3, 5) dtype=float32>}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! I wasn't aware of named outputs; this seems to do the job perfectly. Thanks :D