# Convert Pandas Dataframe as Tensorflow dataset with 2D array as data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

I have constructed a pandas Dataframe with 2 columns which are 'data' and 'label'. 'data' column in a dense matrix and 'label' is integer type.

```py
data     object
label     int64
```

my sample data from dataframe

```py
                                                data   label
0  [[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]], [[[[5 5...      0
1  [[[[[0 0 4 4 1]]]], [[[[0 0 3 3 1]]]], [[[[4 3...      0
2  [[[[[0 0 4 1 2]]]], [[[[0 0 2 3 4]]]], [[[[4 2...      0
3  [[[[[0 0 1 2 5]]]], [[[[0 0 3 2 3]]]], [[[[1 3...      0
4  [[[[[0 0 2 5 5]]]], [[[[0 0 3 4 1]]]], [[[[2 3...      0
```

When I try to convert the Dataframe as Tensorflow dataset it gives me an error. I extracted the labels and data as follows

```py
target = df.pop('label')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values))
```

This gives me the following error.

```py
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got matrix([[0, 5, 1, 4, 4],
        [5, 0, 5, 2, 4],
        [1, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        [4, 4, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

How can I convert my 'data' column to TensorFlow dataset?

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of the data-frame? I am confused how can you have a matrix in a column of a pandas data-frame.

Comment: @gorjan I have updated the sample from my dataframe. Please take a look

Comment: Can you do `print(df.values.shape)`?

Comment: @gorjan, Its ''(9, 2)''.

Comment: Maybe you need `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`. You can refer [Creating a tensorflow dataset that outputs a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136862/creating-a-tensorflow-dataset-that-outputs-a-dict).

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the Tensorflow Version which you are using, I have tried it with Tensorflow version 2.2.0, and below is the working code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

**Creating sample DataFrame same as yours.**

```
s = "[[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]]"
df = pd.DataFrame({"data":s*9,"label":[1]*9})
```

**DataFrame shape:**

```
df.values.shape
(9, 2)
```

**Now creating Tensorflow Dataset:**

```
target = df.pop('label')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values))
```

**Result:**

```
for i in dataset.take(1):
  print(i)

(<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=string, numpy=
array([b'[[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]][[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]][[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]][[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]][[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]][[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]][[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]][[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]][[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]],[[[[0 0 5 4 5]]]], [[[[0 0 5 1 4]]]]]'],
      dtype=object)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1>)
```